# Installing Geopandas undoes Jupyter installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, conda

I installed `qtconsole` using conda and the command `conda install qtconsole`. Then I was able to open up the console by typing the following command

`jupyter qtconsole`

Later on I found that I needed the `geopandas` package and I installed it by doing:

`conda install geopandas`

This however broke the `qtconsole` installation such that when I type in `jupyter qtconsole` in `cmd` no console appears. Then I thought I would update qtconsole to bring it back by doing `conda update qtconsole`. This worked (ie I got the console to work again). However when I try to import the `geopandas` package in it I get the error

```
 ImportError                               
 Traceback (most recent call last) 
 <ipython-input-1-fc7d1d298f0c     in <module    ()
 ----> 1 import geopandas
 
 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py
 in <module    ()
       2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
       3 
 ----> 4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
       5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis
       6 from geopandas.tools import sjoin
 
 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py
 in <module    ()
       1 import os
       2 
 ----> 3 import fiona
       4 import numpy as np
       5 import six
 
 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py
 in <module    ()
      67 from six import string_types
      68 
 ---> 69 from fiona.collection import Collection, BytesCollection, vsi_path
      70 from fiona._drivers import driver_count, GDALEnv
      71 from fiona.drvsupport import supported_drivers
 
 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mynewenv\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py
 in <module    ()
       7 
       8 from fiona import compat
 ----> 9 from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
      10 from fiona.ogrext import Session, WritingSession
      11 from fiona.ogrext import (
 
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It seems like `qtconsole` cannot coexist with `geopandas`. This seems strange. How do I fix this?